# How to return similar values on db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a `Trace_Number` that is labeled `Trace Type 'B'` that is provided to me by a vendor.

Whenever we pick up their loads we have our drivers enter in a `Trace Number` that comes into our database as a `Trace Type 'S'`.

Sometimes on the paperwork that our drivers receive the Trace Number value may have a leading number or an extra number may fall after it and as a result it is marked as not matching.

I need a function that will locate the value of Trace Type B within Trace Type S

This is what I currently have

```
SELECT UNIQUE BILL_NUMBER, TRACE.TRACE_NUMBER, TRACE_TYPE FROM TLORDER 
INNER JOIN TRACE ON DETAIL_LINE_ID = DETAIL_NUMBER 
WHERE BILL_TO_CODE = 'IPMILLOUT' AND TRACE_TYPE IN ('S','B') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TRACE T WHERE DETAIL_NUMBER = DETAIL_LINE_ID AND TRACE_TYPE = 'B' 
AND TRACE_NUMBER = (SELECT RIGHT(T2.TRACE_NUMBER,10) FROM TRACE T2 WHERE T2.DETAIL_NUMBER = T.DETAIL_NUMBER AND TRACE_TYPE = 'S'))
```

Expected results is

```
Trace B      Trace S 
1234567890 = 000012345678901 (ACCEPT) 
1567123945 = 124515671239453 (ACCEPT)
9846504684 = 314254565468923 (NOT ACCEPT)
```

The reason for not accept is because the string of 9846504684 was not found from trace type S

However accept is because the string from trace type B can be found on S.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: More sample examples and results would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry Gordon! I added more samples

Comment: What about casting your numbers as characters and then compare it with TraceS like '%TraceB%' ?

Comment: Results are not coming in as expected... only returning exact matches.

Comment: There's a `LOCATE` function used to find one string within another.

Comment: ..."Fixing" this on your database side is the wrong answer.  You shouldn't be letting different ids be used this way in the first place.  Among other things, what happens if there are multiple matches?  This has to be a potential logging/auditing/etc problem, too.  It also implies you have a multi-part key, which would be violating good DB design practice.  Oh, and since you can't use an index for the join, this would be **REALLY** slow.  In the long run, you'd be better off fixing things so you don't need to do this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT UNIQUE BILL_NUMBER, TRACE.TRACE_NUMBER, TRACE_TYPE FROM TLORDER 
INNER JOIN TRACE ON DETAIL_LINE_ID = DETAIL_NUMBER 
WHERE BILL_TO_CODE = 'IPMILLOUT' AND TRACE_TYPE IN ('S','B') 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TRACE T WHERE DETAIL_NUMBER = DETAIL_LINE_ID AND  
TRACE_TYPE = 'B' 
AND char(T.TRACE_NUMBER) = (SELECT char(substr(char(T2.TRACE_NUMBER),posstr(char(T2.TRACE_NUMBER),char(T.TRACE_NUMBER)),10)) FROM TRACE T2 WHERE  
T2.DETAIL_NUMBER = T.DETAIL_NUMBER AND TRACE_TYPE = 'S'))
```

Comment: You're... finding the position of the string so you can extract it and compare it to the search string?  Why not just use `EXISTS` and avoid about half that line?  Although there are far more serious problems with the original statement to begin with...

Comment: I have an error messages returned. "A LIKE predicate or POSSTR scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string expression or the second operand is not a string. SQL STATE = 42824"